# How to move two points of geolocation with keeping distance between them

Tags: geometry

I have two points of location with certain longitude and latitude. My goal to move them so that longitude and latitude will change but distance remained as before.

[This image illustrates what I need to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdkuI.png)

[image]

I will be grateful for a help you can provide.

Comment: so basically you want a circle as though laid out on the surface of a sphere.

Comment: I want to move two geolocation points for example in parallel with Greenwich meridian and save distance between them. The latitude and longitude of new location positions should stay on earth surface.

Answer (score 0):

The "proper" way to do this is with [Vincenty's direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vincenty%27s_formulae#Direct_Problem) algorithm.  That takes the exact ellipsoid flatness parameter into account.  There are simpler methods if you're willing to accept a spherical approximation.

Answer (score 0):

I've got what I needed in my circumstances. I just convert the location to Descartes coordinate system,  move points using linear algebra matrix rotation to a particular direction in Vector 3.
\begin{alignedat}{1}R_{x}(\theta )&={\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&\cos \theta &-\sin \theta \\[3pt]0&\sin \theta &\cos \theta \\[3pt]\end{bmatrix}}\\[6pt]R_{y}(\theta )&={\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &0&\sin \theta \\[3pt]0&1&0\\[3pt]-\sin \theta &0&\cos \theta \\\end{bmatrix}}\\[6pt]R_{z}(\theta )&={\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta &0\\[3pt]\sin \theta &\cos \theta &0\\[3pt]0&0&1\\\end{bmatrix}}\end{alignedat}